# SQLite page_size change using vacuum inVB.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Quoting from the SQLite web page 
" If the page_size pragma is used to specify a new page size just prior to running the VACUUM command and if the database is not in WAL journal mode then VACUUM will change the page size to the new value."

My SQLite 3.7 database is running on 1024 page size and since Im using windows I thought I would try 4096 and see what would happen. I cant for the life of me get it to change, could someone please look at my code and tell me where Im screwing up, thank you

```
 Dim connection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(conectionString)
            connection.Open()
            Dim oMainQueryR As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand
            oMainQueryR.Connection = connection
            oMainQueryR.CommandText = ("PRAGMA page_size=4096")
            oMainQueryR.ExecuteNonQuery()

            oMainQueryR = New SQLite.SQLiteCommand
            oMainQueryR.Connection = connection
            oMainQueryR.CommandText = ("vacuum")
            oMainQueryR.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
```

The vacuum comand runs OK its just that it dosent reset the pagesize, and Im not running WAL

Comment: Does it work if you run these commands in sqlite3.exe?

Comment: Im ussing the Dll, I dont know a first thing about the exe

Comment: The [shell](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

Comment: I dont think I can use the shell as the database is encrypted. But I'll have a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the encryprion, take that off and the code works as bellow. Thank you to C.L who made me think ! If you dont have encryption then just delete the 2 references to ChangePasswords. Interestingly the database grew by about 10% setting the Page Size to 4096 from default 1024.

```
        Dim connection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(conectionString)
        connection.Open()
        connection.ChangePassword("")
        Dim oMainQueryR As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand
        oMainQueryR.Connection = connection
        oMainQueryR.CommandText = ("PRAGMA page_size=") & Val(Me.TextBox254.Text) & "; vacuum"
        oMainQueryR.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.ChangePassword(previous password)

        connection.Close()
```